# Replacement rule not having desired effect

Tags: replacement

So I have this replacement rule that tends to work in most cases, except occasionally in cases like this:

```
p[{3, 4}] p[{5, 6}] p[{1, 4, 6}] p[{2, 3, 5}] //. 
  {p[list1_] p[list2_] :> 
    If[Length[Intersection[list1, list2]] != 0, p[Union[list1, list2]]]}
```

the problem seems to be that every time it evaluates the replacement rule, it only looks at the first two terms. If there's no replacement to be done it then just doesn't do anything. Does anybody know a way to maybe "scramble" the terms in the list or make the replacement look at every part of the expression?

Comment: You need a case when `If` evaluates to `False`, probably `p[{3, 4}] p[{5, 6}] p[{1, 4, 6}] p[{2, 3, 
    5}] //. {p[list1_] p[list2_] -> 
   If[Length[Intersection[list1, list2]] != 0, p[Union[list1, list2]],
     p[list1] p[list2]]}` ?

Comment: @rhermans I tried that, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: *Please* use a title that describes your problem!!!

Comment: Do you *only* want to merge the lists from neighbouring elements of the product or any pair of elements of the product?  (@belisariusisforth is right that Orderless is going to make "neighbouring" somewhat slippery.)  Consider `p[{1,2}] p[{2,3}] p[{4}] p[{5,6}] p[{6,1}]` .

Comment: Any pair of elements. So for your example the output would ideally be `p[{1,2,3,5,6}] p[{4}]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to do it is to make sure you allow for other terms that aren't part of the match, like so:

```
In[1]:= p[{3, 4}] p[{5, 6}] p[{1, 4, 6}] p[{2, 3, 5}] //.
         Times[before___p, p[l1_List], between___p, p[l2_List], after___p] /; 
           Intersection[l1, l2] =!= {} :> 
          Times[p[Union[l1, l2]], before, between, after]
Out[1]= p[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

Comment: Ha! `before, between, after` sounds funny :)

Comment: This worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

You can condition your pattern match with `ContainsAny`.

```
rep = {p[list1_] p[list2_] /; ContainsAny[list1, list2] :> p[Union[list1, list2]]};

p[{3, 4}] p[{5, 6}] p[{1, 4, 6}] p[{2, 3, 5}] //. rep
(* p[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}] *)

p[{3, 4}] p[{5, 6}] p[{8, 10}] p[{1, 4, 6}] p[{2, 3, 5}] //. rep
(* p[{8, 10}] p[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}] *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This does immensely! Thank you!!

Comment: this actually doesn't seem to work how it should. Even if I input the example you give it doesn't change it. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: In a new notebook run `ClearAll[p, list1, list2, rep]` and then the code above.

Comment: Same problem. The first just returns `p[{3,4}] p[{5,6}] p[{1,4,6}] p[{2,3,5}]`

Comment: so this works for you when you enter it? I'm assuming it's just something wrong with my setup.

Comment: What version are you running? `ContainsAny` was added in 10.2.  If your version is below 10.2 then replace `ContainsAny[list1, list2]` with `(Length[Intersection[list1, list2]] != 0)`, this is the test from your `If` statement.

Comment: That may have been my problem. I'll try to update